# Can't do a post request using axios, returning unauthorised 401 error

Tags: redux, axios

I created an auth service from scratch using Redux, React and Node. Everything was working fine until I wire up my Post section o redux to my BackEnd. The redux part is ok I guess. My problem is when I send the Authorization Bearer token. I'm being able to post using insomnia. But when I try to post using the web app I can't.
This is my action:

```
export const createPost = ( formValues: any) => async(dispatch: any, getState: any) => {
  const { userId } = getState().auth;
  let token = userId

  const headers = {
    header: {
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
      'Accept' : 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  };
  const response = await AlleSys.post('/posts', {...formValues, headers})
  // dispatch({type: CREATE_POST, payload: response.data})
```

userId is my JWT token.

I already set up Cors on my backend

```
const corsOptions ={
    origin:'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials:true,            //access-control-allow-credentials:true
    optionSuccessStatus:200
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```

On Insomnia. The same request on insomnia works fine.
[image]

[image]

On insomnia I'm using the same bearer token from my application, so the problem is not the JWT.

Answer (score 0):

Querying an endpoint with GET, POST, PUT, DELETE from a Nodejs server or Insomnia will result in calling before checking the OPTIONS.

But browsers will limit the HTTP requests to be at the same domain which makes you run into CORS issues. Since Insomnia is not a browser and CORS is a browser security restriction only, it didn't get limited.

From [docs](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight) for the CORS you are using:

> Certain CORS requests are considered 'complex' and require an initial OPTIONS request (called the "pre-flight request"). An example of a 'complex' CORS request is one that uses an HTTP verb other than GET/HEAD/POST (such as DELETE) or that uses custom headers. To enable pre-flighting, you must add a new OPTIONS handler for the route you want to support:

So I think you should include app.options('*', cors()) before all routes and put it at the top of your file to be processed first.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code to:

```
export const createPost = ( formValues: any) => async(dispatch: any, getState: any) => {
  const { userId } = getState().auth;
  let token = userId

  const headers = {
    authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
  };
  const response = await AlleSys.post('/posts', {...formValues}, {headers})
```

And Worked!